If the current frequency is within the human hearing range, why can't we hear it?
If the current frequency (50 Hz or 60 Hz) falls within the human hearing range (20 Hz to 20 kHz), why can’t we hear it?

Stand next to a large transformer. You can't hear the EM wave, but you can certainly hear the transformer vibrating.

Does the sound produced by a vibrating transformer match the 50 Hz or 60 Hz frequency of the current, or is it a different frequency?

Yes, the sound matches the current frequency, and its harmonics. Transformer hum from appliances was very common back before switched-mode power supplies became common.

Just for the record: Your ears hear vibrations of the molecules in the air. They don't hear EM waves, regardless of the frequency. Only if the electrical signal is somehow converted to an air pressure wave are you going to hear it.

@PM2Ring I'm liking 120 Hz (B2) in the states: https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/ which makes sense that it's doubled for sound vs voltage. Or 60 Hz square wave, which has a lot of 120. May need to redo with headphones for the behs.


If the current frequency (50 Hz or 60 Hz) falls within the human hearing range (20 Hz to 20 kHz), why can’t we hear it?

Human ears detect vibration of air molecules inside the ear. If some object is moving, in air, at frequency $f$, then it will vibrate the air around the object and create sound waves the propagate to our ear. Our ear can then sense the sound waves as sound.
If there is AC current through some circuit at frequency $f$ then that means

electrons are oscillating at frequency $f$
electric and magnetic fields around the circuit are also oscillating at frequency $f$.

However, the human ear doesn't sense electrons moving or electric or magnetic fields. This is why humans do not generally "hear" AC circuits at 50 or 60 Hz.
However, AC currents create changing magnetic fields. If the currents are large then these large magnetic fields can create forces on magnetic materials in the vicinity of the circuit (for example the magnets in large transformers). These magnetic forces cause the magnetic materials to physically move. This physical motion can generate sound. So, in some cases, the electric circuits can create sounds that are picked up by human ears.

An effect of an applied voltage is that electrons start moving. These moving electrons (current) interact with the material (your conductor) they are moving through, inducing some vibrations (sound). However these vibrations are very, very small, meaning that we couldn't hear them.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
